# Troubleshooting Elastic Beanstalk Node.js Deployment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It's my first time trying out Elastic Beanstalk, up until now I've had a node/express app manually set up and running on a single ec2 instance.

I'm using the console (web ui) to upload a zip of my node app, everything appears successful in the console and the monitoring health is constantly green/healthy, but when I got to the url elastic beanstalk provides (http://{my app}.elasticbeanstalk.com/) I expected to get to the root page of my node/express app but instead the response is just a number '2'.

Anyone know how I can debug this? I have taken a look at the snapshot logs and things seem fine there too, the node app has logged out that it has started and is listening and there are no errors. Earlier I had a problem where I had a nginx bad gateway but that was because I was listening on the wrong port, that was fixed.

I can ssh into the ec2 instance if that would help but not sure really how to debug elastic beanstalk issues, I'm used to just deploying things myself!

Comment: First thing I would recommend is snapshot logs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html

Comment: Unfortunately there are no errors in the snapshot logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies. Those were my own error messages telling me there are internal server errors taking place for various reasons. So it's no surprise there were no errors in the logs. The application just needs updating, some paths, nothing to do with elastic beanstalk or node, it was my code.